# Primefaces Picklist trigger transfer event only on add

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a picklist component (Primefaces 6.x ) in one of my pages. The picklist has a "transfer" event listener as shown in the showcase:

```
<p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListView.onTransfer}" update="msg" />
```

This works pretty well and my method is called every time i add or remove items from the target list.

My question is if it is possible to trigger the event handler only when adding items in the target list or if there is a way to catch the remove from target action in my method and ignore all validations that i am doing in bean method.

Comment: As I can see the button events defined by css. There is no overwritable js code. You can just do the filtering on the server side. Maybe you can redefine the class types linked to the buttons. (.ui-picklist-button-add, .ui-picklist-button-add-all, ...)

Comment: What do you mean by filtering on the server? Is there a way to identify on the server side if it is an add or a remove action ?

Comment: I just dig the generated source and the css. But as I can see there is a `select` and an `unselect` event type in the showcase. It is not a good solution for you?

Comment: No, because the select is getting triggered only when you select the entry from the list and not when you assign it to the target list.

Comment: The signiture of the `transfer` event handler is : `public void onTransfer(org.primefaces.event.TransferEvent evenet_)`. This event object has two methods `isAdd` and `isRemove` with others : https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/event/TransferEvent.html

Comment: @TheBitman: Sorry I only read all comments after I posted my answer. If you want to create one, go ahead and I'll remove mine. But PLEASE next time refer to current api's (OP stated 6.1 is used, not 3.4)

Comment: @Kukeltje There is no problem! I gave you an upvote as well! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an advantage to source being open and having a good IDE for code completion. Both can show that the [`TransferEvent.java`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/event/TransferEvent.java) has `isAdd()` and `isRemove()` methods. These can easily be used to differentiate in an eventHandler which one is actually used.

```
public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {

   if (event.isAdd()) {
      // Do actual work
   }

}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted. Thank you.